# Steel Catch 22 in Starbound

Tags: starbound

> Note: This question refers to content found only in Starbound beta. **As of the 1.0 stable version of the game, Steel is not available in the game.** It has been replaced with tungsten, which is directly mined as ore and melted into tungsten bars in a furnace.

I want to make Steel bars

To make steel you need iron and oil

to collect oil you need an upgraded Matter Manipulator

to upgrade the Matter Manipulator you need refined copper

to refine copper you need a Refinery

to make a Refinery you NEED STEEL!!!

this is impossible

Comment: Never mind, it says refined, but it just means a copper bar

Comment: I'm sure a regular furnace (made of stone and a camp fire) can smelt copper for you... And a refinery is used for turning ores into pixels...

Answer (score 7):

A [Refinery](http://starbounder.org/Refinery) is a crafting device that allows you to transform ores and their derivatives into pixels. You're looking to smelt Copper Ore into Copper Bars, which you can do at a [Stone Furnace](http://starbounder.org/Stone_Furnace).